# Copy a part of a string to another, of the same string, if a condition is met in R

Tags: r

I have posted a similar question, however, this string today is much more difficult to parse due to another addition of data. I have tried adapting previous answers, used AI, etc., but I have not been able to figure this out.

I have a column C in a dataframe DT that has rows each containing unique strings. I would like to copy one part of the string, the protein ID, to parts of the string that do not have that ID allocated. You can see that most of the values in the brackets have an ID before them, but in C1 and C2 below there is each a set that does not, the O43309 in C1 and the A6H8Y1 in C2, both in front of a blank "1xPhospho". I should note that these 1xPhospho strings can have any number in front, such as 2xPhospho or 5xPhospho. I want the previous ID from right before the blank one to be placed/imputed there. Here is the example. Thank you.

```
C1 <- c("Q99676 1xPhospho [T581(100)]; Q8TBZ5 1xPhospho [T402(100)]; Q9Y2P0 1xPhospho [T413(100)]; Q15776 1xPhospho [T513(100)]; O14978 1xPhospho [T513(100)]; O43309 1xPhospho [T492(100)]; 1xPhospho [T520(100)]; Q9P2J8 1xPhospho [T803(100)]; A6NP11 1xPhospho [T319(100)]")
C2 <- c("A6H8Y1 1xPhospho [T915(100)]; 1xPhospho [T1131(100)]")
C3 <- c("Q9H1B7 1xPhospho [T915(100)]; Q8K3X4 1xPhospho [T915(100)]")

DT <- data.frame(Modifications.of.Proteins = c(C1, C2, C3))

## I would like the output of DT$Modifications.of.Proteins

[1] "Q99676 1xPhospho [T581(100)]; Q8TBZ5 1xPhospho [T402(100)]; Q9Y2P0 1xPhospho [T413(100)]; Q15776 1xPhospho [T513(100)]; O14978 1xPhospho [T513(100)]; O43309 1xPhospho [T492(100)]; O43309 1xPhospho [T520(100)]; Q9P2J8 1xPhospho [T803(100)]; A6NP11 1xPhospho [T319(100)]; O43309 1xPhospho [T492(100)]; O43309 1xPhospho [T520(100)]"
[2] "A6H8Y1 1xPhospho [T915(100)]; A6H8Y1 1xPhospho [T1131(100)]"
[3] "Q9H1B7 1xPhospho [T915(100)]; Q8K3X4 1xPhospho [T915(100)]"
```

Comment: Your `C1` has 9 `;`-delimited strings and your first expected string has 11, are you expecting us to contrive the extra strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```r
fun <- function(S) {
  strsplit(S, ";")[[1]] |>
    strcapture("(.*) ([0-9]+x\\S+ \\[.*)", x = _, list(a = "", b="")) |> 
    transform(a = replace(a, !nzchar(trimws(a)), NA)) |> 
    tidyr::fill(a) |> 
    lapply(trimws) |>
    with(paste(paste(a, b), collapse = "; "))
}
```

I'm using `tidyr::fill` because it's convenient and does what it does well. I could easily use `dplyr::mutate`, that's easy if you are already using it. There are likely other ways to do what `tidyr::fill` is doing, such as `zoo::na.locf`.

```r
> unname(sapply(DT$Modifications.of.Proteins, fun))
[1] "Q99676 1xPhospho [T581(100)]; Q8TBZ5 1xPhospho [T402(100)]; Q9Y2P0 1xPhospho [T413(100)]; Q15776 1xPhospho [T513(100)]; O14978 1xPhospho [T513(100)]; O43309 1xPhospho [T492(100)]; O43309 1xPhospho [T520(100)]; Q9P2J8 1xPhospho [T803(100)]; A6NP11 1xPhospho [T319(100)]"
[2] "A6H8Y1 1xPhospho [T915(100)]; A6H8Y1 1xPhospho [T1131(100)]"                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[3] "Q9H1B7 1xPhospho [T915(100)]; Q8K3X4 1xPhospho [T915(100)]"
```

(`unname` here primarily for in-answer aesthetics ... it's a self-named vector, so the names are rather distracting. Removing the names is not required.)

Comment: This is pretty good! Thanks! the only issue is there is no space after the [T915(100)]; in [2], so "A6H8Y1 1xPhospho [T915(100)];A6H8Y1 1xPhospho [T1131(100)]"  should be "A6H8Y1 1xPhospho [T915(100)]; A6H8Y1 1xPhospho [T1131(100)]" but I'll give it a go! Appreciate your help!

Comment: @JohnH try my edit, using a combination of `trimws` and jpsmith's recommended `collapse="; "`.

Comment: Frankly, for most types of analysis I think I'd do on data like this, I would much prefer to break it out into individual genes/proteins (storing its original row/position) and keeping them separate. Granted, I don't know what you're doing so it's a stretch, but consider breaking it out (as `strsplit` does) and keeping it split up. It's not hard to turn that into a long-format frame (not list-columns as `strsplit` tends to make) with grouping calculations/aggregations.